# Sample 3 random rows then order them alphabetically by another property

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I was just wondering if I can get three random results and then order them by another column alphabetically.

Example:

```
SELECT TOP(3)[Name] 
FROM Table 
ORDER BY NEWID()
¿ORDER BY [Surname]?
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With a TOP, I bet this is mssql

Comment: I removed those conflicting dbms tags. Put one of them back, the one for the dbms actually used.

Comment: Why do you want random rows ?

Comment: @ArnaudPeralta `TOP` is a standard SQL expression. It's `NEWID()` that's specific to SQL Server

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos -   `TOP` is [not standard SQL](http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/#select-limit)

Comment: `TOP` **is not** standard SQL... `FETCH FIRST` is the ANSI SQL way!

Comment: @jarlh I keep forgetting that! Every decade the same thing.

Comment: And we're nearly at the end of this decade so same time next year? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure to understand the problem at 100%, but with a second `ORDER BY` it will sort all of the differents ID.

I did a CTE for achieving this result.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT TOP(3)[Name] 
FROM Table 
ORDER BY NEWID()
)

SELECT *
FROM CTE
ORDER BY [Surname]
```

Comment: Thanks Arnaud, but I had to Select, [Name],[Surname] to work, but it did, THANKS

Comment: Glad to helped you, don't forget to mark this as a good answer and upvote for other people.

Answer (score 1):

Have a *derived table* (sub-query) where you select 3 random rows. `ORDER BY` its result.

```
select [Name]
from
(
    SELECT TOP(3) [Name], [Surname]
    FROM Table 
    ORDER BY NEWID()
) dt
ORDER BY [Surname]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
SELECT T.*
FROM
    (
    SELECT TOP(3)[Name], [Surname]
    FROM Table 
    ORDER BY NEWID()
    ) AS T
ORDER BY [Surname];
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can try this -**

```
declare @name table
(Name varchar(20), SurName varchar(20))

insert into @name
values
('mukesh', 'arora'),
('amit', 'kumar'),
('Vijay', 'gupta'),
('jai', 'poddar'),
('vishal', 'sharma')

select Name from
( 
SELECT TOP(3)[Name] , [Surname]
FROM @name 
ORDER BY NEWID()
) a
ORDER BY [Surname]
```